# How do I import my key using the WebCrypto interface?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, security, encryption

My applications Cryptography currently utilizes the [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) library for encryption, decryption, deriving keys, and importing keys. I recently began reading about [the new cryptographic features that are part of the HTML5 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) and wanted to do a POC to see if it is viable as well as the performance impact.

The feature seems pretty unusable right now. I can't even manage to import any of my keys.

**Byte encoded key**: `"#a×iKº|UF?îçàÂ{ÙîµËËã-cØÊz"`

**B64 encoded key**: `"I2HXaUu6fFVGP4fu5+CJwh57HtnutcvL4y0XY9icyno="`

**Unsigned 8 bit integer array key representation**: `[35, 97, 215, 105, 75, 186, 124, 85, 70, 63, 135, 238, 231, 224, 137, 194, 30, 123, 30, 217, 238, 181, 203, 203, 227, 45, 23, 99, 216, 156, 202, 122]`

I tried importing my key using [JWK](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-gcm---importkey):

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk", //can be "jwk" or "raw"
    {   //this is an example jwk key, "raw" would be an ArrayBuffer
        kty: "oct",
        k: "I2HXaUu6fFVGP4fu5+CJwh57HtnutcvL4y0XY9icyno=",
        alg: "A256GCM",
        ext: true,
    },
    {   //this is the algorithm options
        name: "AES-GCM",
    },
    false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //can "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
)
.then(function(key){
    //returns the symmetric key
    console.log(key);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

But this just results in a promise that never resolves. I then tried to import my key using 'raw' type and passing it the arrayBuffer above:

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw", //can be "jwk" or "raw"
    arrayBuffer,
    {   //this is the algorithm options
        name: "AES-GCM",
    },
    true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //can "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
)
.then(function(key){
    //returns the symmetric key
    console.log(key);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

But this also just results in a promise that never resolves.

How do I import my key using the [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) interface?

Comment: Note that the input is an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) for raw and that object has a description on how to create it. Otherwise you could be able to create an array using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/589259) for raw.

Answer (score 1):

Your base64 encoding is correct, however JWK requires the use of base64url. In that encoding, the key becomes: `I2HXaUu6fFVGP4fu5-CJwh57HtnutcvL4y0XY9icyno`.

When I change `k` to that value, I can successfully import your key.